# Get Row Number in Excel for given Column Number and Cell Data

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, hp-uft

If I know the cell data and the column number where i expect the data to be in. Please let me know how do i retrieve the row number for that cell. 
Thank you.

Comment: Range.Find() or Application.Match()

Comment: @Scott Craner. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way for column **B**:

```
Sub HappinessRow()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("B:B").Find(what:="happiness", after:=Range("B1"))
If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "could not find happiness"
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox "happiness found in row " & r.Row
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This version uses parameters for the value to find, and the column to search:

```
Sub HappinessRow2()

    Dim r As Range, s As String, kolumn As Long

    s = "happiness"
    kolumn = 2

    Set r = Cells(1, kolumn).EntireColumn.Find(what:="happiness", after:=Cells(1, kolumn))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "could not find happiness"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "happiness found in row " & r.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked

Comment: @kingsif if you are using this solution then you should accept his answer.

Comment: @Thomas. I am not using this answer now . I don't want to hard-code my column names in code. Checking if i can use this code. I would definitely accept if i use.

Comment: @kings  How would you like to indicate the column to search ??

Comment: @Gary's Student Let's say I know the column number. For Example,  column number  = 2, data = "happiness". How do i know the row number in second column having data "happiness" ?

Comment: Changing `Set r = Range("B:B").Find(what:="happiness", after:=Range("B1"))` to `Set r = Columns( y ).Find(what:="happiness", after:=Cells(1, y))` and set `y = 2`.

Comment: @kings  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I get an error - Expected ')', when i try this code. It highlights near what:=. I don't see anything wrong in code.

Comment: I removed what and after arguments and just searched for value like Sheet.Cells(1, columnnum).EntireColumn.Find("happiness") - It worked. Thank you Gary's Student and Thomas Inzina.

Answer (score 4):

Use an [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)'s use of a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
dim rw as variant
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    rw = application.match(<value_to_find>, .columns(1), 0)  'column A
    if iserror(rw) then
        'not found - rw is a worksheet error code
    else
        'found - rw is a long integer representing the row number
    end if
end with
```

Comment: Is Application Excel Object or WorkBook Object ?

Comment: Do you mean [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)? What part of the above is not clear? It says `application.match` right in the code.

Comment: I created an object for Excel in VBScript as Set Ex = CreateObject(Excel.Application). Should my syntax be this way : Ex.WorksheetFunction.match(<value_to_find>, .columns(1), 0)

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to use `rw = Ex.match(<value_to_find>, .columns(1), 0)`.

Comment: How do i select a particular worksheet where i need to check the data for row number

Comment: That sounds like a new question. See [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625). Be sure to use **either** [excel-vba] or [vbscript] but not both as this only leads to confusion.

Comment: Got it. Liked the Russian Doll !